No me funciona la impresion de una <table> utilizando javascript
Desde un programa PHP que lee una base de datos MySQL correctamente, luego de validar los datos que se leen de la base de datos utilizo una instrucción require_once "../vistas/modulos/vimprime.php" para invocar el programa que debe realizar la impresión.
La function printWin() no realiza el trabajo esperado de impresión.
Asimismo, cómo puede observarse en el fuente que acabo de adjuntar, también he hecho uso de una etiqueta  en combinación con la function printDiv(impresion) (la cual está entre comentarios en el fuente adjunto) pero tampoco me funciona la impresión.
Agradeceré me apoyen con una solución. Muchas gracias.
`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            @page {
                size: auto;
                margin: 0mm;
            }
            td {
                height: 0px;
                vertical-align: bottom;
            }
            .td_detalle_venta_desc{
                font-size:11px;
                font-family:arial;
                vertical-align:top;
            }
            .td_detalle_venta_num{
                font-size:10px;
                font-family:arial;
                vertical-align:top;
            }
            .div_responsive{
                width: 220px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .div_responsive_2{
                width: 38.2px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .div_responsive_3{
                width: 57.3px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .div_responsive_4{
                width: 76.4px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .div_responsive_5{
                width: 95.7px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .div_responsive_6{
                width: 114.6px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .div_responsive_7{
                width: 132.6px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .div_responsive_8{
                width: 152.8px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="impresion">
        <table border="0" width="230px">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="12" align="center" style="font-size:24px;font-family:arial;font-weight: bold"><div class="div_responsive"><?php echo "PEDIDO: ".$id_pedidocabecera; ?></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="12" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="left" style="font-size:12px;font-family:arial;font-weight: bold;">Descripci贸n</td>
                <td colspan="2" align="center" style="font-size:12px;font-family:arial;font-weight: bold;">Precio</td>
                <td colspan="2" align="center" style="font-size:12px;font-family:arial;font-weight: bold;">Cant.</td>
                <td colspan="2" align="right" style="font-size:12px;font-family:arial;font-weight: bold;">Importe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="12" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;"></td></tr>

            <?php

            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
            $fecha_actual = date('Y/m/d', strtotime ("-5 Hours"));
            $hora_actual = date('H:i:s', strtotime ("-5 Hours"));

            for($i = 0; $i < count($idProductos); $i ++){
                
                $det_id_producto= $idProductos[$i];
                $det_descripcion= $descripcionProductos[$i];
                $det_unidadVenta= $unidadVentaProductos[$i];
                $det_igv= $igvProductos[$i];
                $det_precio= $precioProductos[$i];
                $det_cantidad= $cantidadProductos[$i];
                $det_importe= $importeProductos[$i];                

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td colspan="5" align="left" class="td_detalle_venta_desc"><div class="div_responsive_5">' . $det_descripcion . '</div></td>';
                echo '<td colspan="2" align="center" class="td_detalle_venta_num">' .
                      '<div class="div_responsive_2">' . number_format($det_precio, 2, '.', ',') .
                      '</div>' .
                     '</td>';
                echo '<td colspan="2" align="right" class="td_detalle_venta_num"><div class="div_responsive_2">' . 
                         number_format($det_cantidad, 2, '.', ',') . '</div></td>';
                echo '<td colspan="2" align="right" class="td_detalle_venta_num"><div class="div_responsive_3">' . number_format($det_importe, 2, '.', ',') . '</div></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            ?>

            <tr><td colspan="12" style="border-top:1px solid black;"></td></tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" align="right" style="font-size:12px;font-family:arial;font-weight: bold;"><div class="div_responsive_7">Total: &nbsp;&nbsp;S/.</div></td>
                <td colspan="4" align="right" style="font-size:12px;font-family:arial;font-weight: bold;"><div class="div_responsive_4"><?php echo $total; ?></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="12" style="border-top:1px solid black;"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="12" align="center" style="font-size:11px;font-family:arial;font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $fecha_actual.' '.$hora_actual ; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td>.</td></tr>

        </table>
        
     </div>   

        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        
            var da = (document.all) ? 1 : 0;
            var pr = (window.print) ? 1 : 0;
            var mac = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") != -1);
            
/*
            function printDiv(impresion) {
                 var contenido= document.getElementById(impresion).innerHTML;
                 var contenidoOriginal= document.body.innerHTML;
                
                 document.body.innerHTML = contenido;
            
                 window.print();
            
                 document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;
            }        
            
            printDiv('impresion');
*/

            function printWin() {
                if (pr) {
                    // NS4+, IE5+
                    window.print();
                } else if (!mac) {
                    // IE3 and IE4 on PC
                    VBprintWin();
                } else {
                    // everything else
                    handle_error();
                }
            }

            function handle_error() {
                window.alert('Su navegador no admite la opci贸n de impresi贸n. Presione Control/Opci贸n + P para imprimir.');
                return true;
            }

            printWin();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
`


Qué es lo que no funciona el window.print()?? y como no funciona? arroja un error, no levanta la ventana de impresión?

Yussef Saludos.
Efectivamente, no levanta la ventana de impresión.

Pues cogiendo tu código y pegándolo en https://jsfiddle.net/mdc7kLf4/ es lo primero que hace, abre la ventana de impresión. No se yo si estamos viendo todo el código afectado o no.  ¿Esto que has pegado es lo que contiene el require ese?  Pues seguramente deberemos ver como lo invocas o si te muestra errores de path o en la consola, o vete a saber.

Si el código que he adjuntado es todo el archivo "vimprime.php".
Y si se invoca adecuadamente porque dentro de archivo vimprime.php que es el codigo fuente que he adjuntado coloqué intrucciones para hacer un trace linea por linea y verifique que se ejecutan todas las lineas de codigo de vimprime.php, pero nunca invoca a la ventana de impresión que supuestamente lo debe hacer el script que invoca a la impresión.
Es lo que se me hace muy extraño, por eso recurrí a solicitar ayuda.

Probe con require y con include y no muestra la ventana de impresión en ningún caso.

¿Y has mirado la consola de tu navegador a ver si hay errores de javascript antes?  Pulsa F12 y vete a la pestaña "Consola" y mira si salen cosas en rojo o errores de algun tipo.  El javascript se puede parar antes de llegar al window.print y no darte cuenta de ello.

Gracias por tu respuesta.
No me arroja ningun error el javascript.
Lo que he logrado con desde PHP lo siguiente:
ob_start(); ?>
//  En este espacio genero el codigo HTML que incluye el javascript function printWin() {
<?php
$contenido_html = ob_get_clean();

Y obtengo en $contenido_html todo el html que requiero imprimir, el cual puedo almacenar en una pagina contenido.html la cual puedo ejecutar correctamente desde un browser de internet, pero no logro que se ejecute desde dentro de mi programa php, por lo que hasta ahora no puedo lograr resolver el problema de impresión.